# How to differentiate between Zero and False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am trying to remove 0 from the list. I am using the Following `if`.

```py
mylist = [False,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,"a"]

for i in mylist:
    if i == 0 and not isinstance(i, bool):
        mylist.remove(i)
        mylist.insert(len(mylist),0)

print(mylist)
```

Problem is that this code treats the `False` as zero. Things get complicated when I change the `if` as follows:

```py
for i in mylist:
    if i == 0 and not isinstance(i, bool):
        print(i)
```

This will print only 0 not False. So it seems that the condition of the `if` works well until I do change the list.

Why does this happen?

Comment: The title asks to remove 0 but your code attempts to **insert** to the list. What are you actually trying to do? what is your expected output?

Comment: @DeepSpace I am trying to move the 0 to the end of the list. So in my `if` I'm removing each 0 I find and then add one to the end of the list.

Comment: Please edit your title to match your actual question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try this code, you will see that the IF condition is evaluated true when zero is reached, and not when False is reached. But, when the first zero is reached, you want to remove a zero, so the array is looped until a zero is reached, which happens at first element (False is treated like zero)

```
mylist = [False,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,"a"]

for i in mylist:
    print(i)        
    if i == 0 and not isinstance(i, bool):
        print('Hi Man')
        mylist.remove(i)
```

The following removes all the zeros (not False)

```
mylist = [False,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,"a"]

mylist = [item for item in mylist if item!=0 or isinstance(item, bool)]
```

And with this one you count how many zeros and add them to the end of the list

```
mylist = [False,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,"a"]

count = sum(map(lambda x : x==0 and not isinstance(x,bool), mylist))

mylist = [item for item in mylist if item!=0 or isinstance(item, bool)]

for i in range(0,count):
    mylist.append(0)
```

Comment: I thought that `mylist.remove(i)` will remove the zero which passes the if expression but you say that the `mylist.remove(i)` causes a search for 0, am I right?

Comment: Exactly, because in your code, i is zero, so mylist.remove(i) is the same as mylist.remove(0), so it removes 'a' zero, not 'that' zero

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the element using from list using its index. You can take example of below code snippet:

```
mylist = [False,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,'a']
for index, i in enumerate(mylist):
    if i==0 and not isinstance(i, bool):
        del mylist[index]
print mylist
```

Output:

`[False, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 'a']`

If you now want to add this zero to end of list you can use the statement `mylist.append(mylist[index])` **BEFORE** the the statement `del mylist[index]`.

New Output will be:

`[False, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 'a', 0, 0]`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with the `if` condition, but with [`list.remove()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types). This function goes over the list and checks for **equality** and hence removes the `False` too:

> `s.remove(x)`  -  remove **the first** item from *s* where `s[i]` is
>   **equal** to *x*.

---

Since you want to move the zeros to the right, your problem is equivalent to a sort where `0` is considered the biggest element. So this simple code will do:

```py
>>> mylist = [False, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, "a"]
>>> mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x is 0)
>>> mylist
[False, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 'a', 0, 0]
```

Note the use of `is` instead of equality which eliminates the detection of `False` (because `False == 0` but `False is not 0`)

Answer (score 0):

Zero is a constant, so you can use `is` as a test to match it exactly:

```
> list(filter(lambda i: i is not 0, mylist)) + list(filter(lambda i: i is 0, mylist))
[False, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 'a', 0, 0]
```